# Cannot create instances of the Types contained in the loaded Silverlight Prism XAP modules

Tags: silverlight, prism, mef, xap

My Silverlight PRISM application is loading several XAP modules. I want to be able to get access to the types contained in the loaded modules so I could create instances of the views and modelviews BEFORE shell is activated. 
I am trying to implement something like this:

```
                AggregateCatalog.Changed+=(o, e)=>
                                          {
                                              var type =
                                                  Type.GetType(
                                                      "mytype, assemblyname");
}
```

but the type is always null :( 
Please help.

Comment: .. by the time you call `Type.GetType()`, did you make sure that the module in which this type is defined has been loaded? also, please write the actual string in the method you're calling.

Comment: Yes, I am actually trying to get type from the e.AddedExports

Comment: I found what was the problem - imported part was not composed - i.e. but after I explicitely triggered Container.ComposeParts(this) it started picking up the typed correctly.

Comment: yeah, MEF is a nice container but takes time to learn ....